# Turn off HTML Designer in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to turn off the HTML designer in Visual Studio 2005?

I know you can tell it to go to the source code view directly, which I've done. But if I'm in the code behind and I press `Shift + F7` to go to the `.aspx` page it goes to the designer rather than the source `.aspx` code. I never use the designer because it's slow and inaccurate. I prefer to edit the `.aspx` code and work side by side with the browser.

So can I turn off the designer entirely?

Answer (score 1):

```
Go to Tools --> Select Options

Select HTML Designer --> Uncheck HTML designer

Click OK
```

***After doing this restart your Visual Studio***

Comment: I don't have this checkbox in my application. And yes, I've checked Show All Settings. I see a group box for Start Pages in and a Smart Tags checkbox, nothing else on the General page

Comment: Ok Select start pages in source view

Comment: I did this. But if I'm in the codebehind and I press Shift + F7 it doesn't go to the source view, it goes to the design view. If I double click the page in the solution explorer, it does go to the source view.

Answer (score 0):

Options...
Text Editor > HTML/XML > Format
Uncheck Apply Automatic Formatting When switching from Design to HTML/XML view

Open aspx page in source view only:
Right-click some file, Open With..., select Source Code Editor, click Set as Default

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the action that the key combination Shift-F7 points to.  The default for Shift-F7 (if you're using the Visual C# 2005 keyboard layout) is `View.ViewDesigner`.  You probably want `View.ViewMarkup`.

You can remap function keys in the Keyboard window, under Tools/Customize.  Click the Keyboard button.